# How to let's everyone point there domain to my folder on debian/ apache2?

Tags: apache, debian, cname

Let's me give you an example:  Blogger.com.

You can create a CNAME in domain DNS to point it to ghs.google.com. After config in blogger's cpanel. Your domain is good to go. You can go to blog.mydomain.com and it will point you direct to your blog.

I'm have a debian/apache2 VPS.And domain tienganhratde.com. I want everyone can point there CNAME to service.tienganhratde.com and they'll see the content of a folder on my VPS. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
Point your default apache/nginx to your app folder

Use Server uri to know which domain are connecting to your website.

Check within your database and show to suitable page